# How to let kea-dhcp4-server wait on postgresql database being ready during boot on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

My kea-dhcp4-server has a dependency on my postgresql database. After a fresh boot the dhcp server has an error like:

```bash
    sudo systemctl status kea-dhcp4-server
× kea-dhcp4-server.service - Kea IPv4 DHCP daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kea-dhcp4-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kea-dhcp4-server.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-02-11 17:09:18 UTC; 11min ago
       Docs: man:kea-dhcp4(8)
    Process: 1104 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/kea-dhcp4 -c /etc/kea/kea-dhcp4.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1104 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 39ms

Feb 11 17:09:18 ns1 systemd[1]: Started Kea IPv4 DHCP daemon.
Feb 11 17:09:18 ns1 kea-dhcp4[1104]: 2024-02-11 17:09:18.166 ERROR [kea-dhcp4.dhcp4/1104.140666424032896] DHCP4_CONFIG_LOAD_FAIL configuration error using file: /etc/kea/kea-dhcp4.conf, reason: Unable to open database: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection>
Feb 11 17:09:18 ns1 kea-dhcp4[1104]:         Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
Feb 11 17:09:18 ns1 kea-dhcp4[1104]: 2024-02-11 17:09:18.166 ERROR [kea-dhcp4.dhcp4/1104.140666424032896] DHCP4_INIT_FAIL failed to initialize Kea server: configuration error using file '/etc/kea/kea-dhcp4.conf': Unable to open database: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432>
Feb 11 17:09:18 ns1 kea-dhcp4[1104]:         Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
Feb 11 17:09:18 ns1 systemd[1]: kea-dhcp4-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 11 17:09:18 ns1 systemd[1]: kea-dhcp4-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

So it seems like the Postgresql database is started later and/or isn't ready yet.
Note: When I start this kea-dhcp4-sever service manually everything works fine.

I've tried different options in editing the kea-dhcp4-server.service using:

```bash
sudo systemctl edit kea-dhcp4-server
```

Tested both with Wants=,After=, and Requires= but no luck.

Could even be a circular dependency between Postgres <== Network ==> Dhcp server?

So my question:
How to let kea-dhcp4-server wait on postgresql database being ready during boot on Ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Perhaps I was typing to much in the override.conf for the kea-dhcp4-server.service. When I tried this the boot order became right and working:

```
more /etc/systemd/system/kea-dhcp4-server.service.d/override.conf
[Unit]
Requires=postgresql.service
After=postgresql.service
```